# Losing detailsview dropdownlist values after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a dropdownlist inside a detailsview and it populates well, but when I do a insert there is a postback so I'm trying to bind the DDL again but the values are lost somehow.

My aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="InsertPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="0">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow SkinID="tableheaderrowSkin">
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell BackColor="DarkGray" BorderColor="DarkGray" BorderWidth="1" Width="300">
                    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="nFuturesId"
                            DataSourceID="FutureCommodityODS" DefaultMode="Insert" OnItemInserting="DetailsView1_ItemInserting"
                            SkinID="detailsviewSkin" OnItemInserted="DetailsView1_ItemInserted" EnableModelValidation="True">

                            <BrummerComp:SortableDropDownList ID="DropDownListFuturesInsert" runat="server"  SkinID="BCdropdownlistSkin">
                            </BrummerComp:SortableDropDownList>  
                    </asp:DetailsView>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I populate the DDL in Page_Load:

```
protected new void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    if (!IsPostBack) {
        BindDropDownList();
    }

    //DetailsView1.DataBind();

}
```

BindDropDownList:

```
private void BindDropDownList()
{
    var paperFutureList = (List<PaperFutures>)DataManager.GetPaperFutures();
    var ddl = (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownListFuturesInsert");
    ddl.DataSource = paperFutureList;
    ddl.DataValueField = "nFuturesID";
    ddl.DataTextField = "ShortNameAndFutureNameAndFutureId";
    ddl.DataBind();
}
```

The problem is when I do a insert in my detailsview the DDL is loses it's values. I have tried databind the detailsview but then the values won't load at all.

The method BindDropDownList works well in Page_Load the first time. Also tried putting the methodcall outside !IsPostBack to always populate it but that doesn't work either.

I have checked GetPaperFutures() and it works well every time, so the problem is somewhere else, but I can't find where.

Comment: Clear the datasource and bind again!

Comment: Tried using ddl.Items.Clear in Page_Load but still don't work

Comment: Not inside page load! while binding! ddl.DataSource = null;
    comboBox1.DataSource = paperFutureList;

Comment: Tried clearing it inside BindDropDownList before ddl.DataSource = paperFutureList but still not working.

Comment: Make sure that the EnableViewState equals true for the page and DropDownList

Comment: It's true both in DDL and Page

Comment: You still need to bind Detailsview and DDL on Postback.

Comment: But when binding Detailsview the DDL values doesn't load?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar problem. Eventually, I have found the solution!

**Just call the BindDropDownList() in Page_PreRender event.**

It works successfully!